# Hyperloop Swift Generation failed with unknown or unsupported type (AVCaptureSession)

Tags: ios, swift, appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

I have a simple Swift class that works fine in the XCode 8.1 project it was created with (there is more in the class but the example was cut down for brevity).

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

public class ExampleView: UIView {

   let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
   var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

   override init (frame : CGRect) {
      super.init(frame : frame)
   }

   convenience init () {
      self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
   }

   required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
   }

   func doSomething(){
      print("do something here.....")
   }
}
```

And is used in in viewDidLoad()

```
let example = ExampleView(frame: self.view.layer.frame);
example.doSomething()
```

I created new Hyperloop iOS project (SDK 5.5.1.GA) and added this into a src dir along with an associated appc.js. But every time the app compiles I get as far as the Hyperloop compile and it fails with the following

```
[TRACE] :  [Hyperloop] metabase took 2243 ms to generate
2016-10-30T15:39:31.675Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property '1' of null
2016-10-30T15:39:31.676Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property '1' of null
```

So I then tried adding this file into the **src** directory of the **hyperloop-examples** project, but this also give me the following error

```
[TRACE] :  [Hyperloop] metabase took 2425 ms to generate
Swift Generation failed with unknown or unsupported type (AVCaptureSession)     found while compiling /Users/accountone/hyperloop-examples/src/MyExample.swift
```

What am I doing wrong and any suggestions on how to correct the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `AVFoundation` framework to the `appc.js` file?

Comment: I hadn't as the example appc.js states that Hyperloop will determine the required frameworks, but I have now added it the the framworks list. But I still get the same error.